# Can I use a short code from the parent account in a business unit?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I have a short code for mobile connect provisioned for my parent account and wondered if I could transfer it to a child account or do I have to ask for short codes for every business unit?

Comment: Could you provide a sample ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in short.

MobileConnect can be provisioned in one of two ways:

- A single shared instance where contacts and codes are shared by all BUs.
- Separate siloed instances for each Business Unit.

If this is a new Marketing Cloud account and the former method sounds like the best fit for you, then I'd raise a case to Support to have the provisioning done with a single instance as this can be pretty useful for sharing contacts across the org as well as for sharing codes and avoiding the need for imports to MobileConnect from each of the child MIDs.

If this is an established SFMC MobileConnect setup or you want a degree of segmentation of contact data between MIDs, I'd raise a case requesting that the short code be provisioned to the MIDs you require.